# How to Load Nested JSON data into an ExpendableListView

Tags: c#, json, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

This time I’m experimenting with the **ExpendableListView** in my app (with Xamarin.Android)

I followed the tutorial on this site: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/677206/MonoAndroid-Writing-ExpandableListView-amd

I managed to get the sample working in my own project, but now I’m trying to load my json data into the expendable listview. My json has nested objects and I don’t know how I can load this nested data into an expendable listview.

What I want to achieve is to get the startTime (only the date) into the header and all the rest within chargingPointID and time into the childview.

**JSON**

```
[
 {
  "_id": "56e951fc2c559594037ceb7c",
  "endTime": "2016-03-20T14:00:00.287Z",
  "startTime": "2016-03-20T12:00:00.287Z",
  "chargingPointID": {
     "_id": "56e1815b78ac6b100f5de0d7",
     "price": 5.55,
     "type": "TypeBart",
     "address": "Van Vaerenberghstraat 11, 2600 Antwerpen, Belgia"
  },
  "userID": "56d05d7a475fec041bc2cab5",
  "__v": 0,
  "modified_at": "2016-03-16T12:30:52.034Z",
  "created_at": "2016-03-16T12:30:52.034Z"
},
{
  "_id": "56e952062c559594037ceb7d",
  "endTime": "2016-03-20T18:00:00.287Z",
  "startTime": "2016-03-20T17:00:00.287Z",
  "chargingPointID": {
    "_id": "56e1815b78ac6b100f5de0d7",
    "price": 5.55,
    "type": "TypeBart",
    "address": "Van Vaerenberghstraat 11, 2600 Antwerpen, Belgia"
  },
  "userID": "56d05d7a475fec041bc2cab5",
  "__v": 0,
  "modified_at": "2016-03-16T12:31:02.698Z",
  "created_at": "2016-03-16T12:31:02.698Z"
},
{
  "_id": "56e952182c559594037ceb7e",
  "endTime": "2016-03-21T18:00:00.287Z",
  "startTime": "2016-03-21T17:00:00.287Z",
  "chargingPointID": {
    "_id": "56e181d078ac6b100f5de0d8",
    "price": 17.99,
    "type": "TypeNG",
    "address": "Osystraat 59, 2060 Antwerpen, Belgia"
  },
  "userID": "56d05d7a475fec041bc2cab5",
  "__v": 0,
  "modified_at": "2016-03-16T12:31:20.655Z",
  "created_at": "2016-03-16T12:31:20.655Z"
}
]
```

**ExpendListAdapter.cs**

```
public class ExpendListAdapter: BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string> > _dictGroup = null;
    List<string> _lstGroupID = null;
    Activity _activity;

    public ExpendListAdapter (Activity activity,
                              Dictionary<string, List<string> > dictGroup)
    {
        _dictGroup = dictGroup;
        _activity = activity;
        _lstGroupID = dictGroup.Keys.ToList ();

    }

    #region implemented abstract members of BaseExpandableListAdapter

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return _dictGroup [_lstGroupID [groupPosition]] [childPosition];
    }

    public override long GetChildId (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public override int GetChildrenCount (int groupPosition)
    {
        return _dictGroup [_lstGroupID [groupPosition]].Count;
    }

    public override View GetChildView (int groupPosition,
                                       int childPosition,
                                       bool isLastChild,
                                       View convertView,
                                       ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _dictGroup [_lstGroupID [groupPosition]] [childPosition];

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListControl_ChildItem, null);

        var textBox = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtSmall);
        textBox.SetText (item, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

        return convertView;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup (int groupPosition)
    {
        return _lstGroupID [groupPosition];
    }

    public override long GetGroupId (int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public override View GetGroupView (int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = _lstGroupID [groupPosition];

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.ListControl_Group, null);

        var textBox = convertView.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtLarge);
        textBox.SetText (item, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

        return convertView;
    }

    public override bool IsChildSelectable (int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override int GroupCount {
        get {
            return _dictGroup.Count;
        }
    }

    public override bool HasStableIds {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**MyReservationActivity.cs**

```
public class MyReservationsActivity : Activity
{
    Button buttonMyHome;

    Dictionary<string, List<string> > dictGroup = new Dictionary<string, List<string> > ();
    List<string> lstKeys = new List<string> ();

    List<MyReservationClass> result = new List<MyReservationClass> ();

    protected async override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MyReservationsLayout);

        CreateExpendableListData ();

        var ctlExListBox = FindViewById<ExpandableListView> (Resource.Id.ctlExListBox);
        ctlExListBox.SetAdapter (new ExpendListAdapter (this, dictGroup));

        buttonMyHome = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btn_home);

        try {
            string pathUrl = "reservations/myReservations/"; //locatie van laadpalen
            string currentToken = Settings.Token; //steek token in variabele
            string currentUserID = Settings.User_ID;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("My token: " + currentToken);

            var getResponse = await RequestClass.GetMyReservations (pathUrl, currentToken, currentUserID);//Doe een get request en steek response in variabele
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("My GETresponse: " + getResponse.ToString ());

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyReservationClass>> (getResponse);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Check error: " + ex);
        }


        buttonMyHome.Click += ButtonMyHome_Click;
    }

    void ButtonMyHome_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(HomeActivity));
        Finish ();
    }

    void CreateExpendableListData ()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
            var lstChild = new List<string> ();
            for (int j = 0; j < result [i].chargingPointID; j++) {
                Console.WriteLine (j);
            }
            dictGroup.Add (string.Format (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime).ToShortDateString ()), lstChild);
        }

        lstKeys = new List<string> (dictGroup.Keys);

    }
}
```

if i do this: `for (int j = 0; j < result [i].chargingPointID; j++)`

i will get an error saying the following:

> the operator ‘<’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘int’ and ‘CharchingPointID’

I've also tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
            var lstChild = new List<string> ();
            for (int j = 0; j < result.Count; j++) {
                lstChild.Add (string.Format (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime).ToShortDateString (), result [i].chargingPointID));
            }
            dictGroup.Add (string.Format (Convert.ToDateTime (result [i].startTime).ToShortDateString ()), lstChild);
        }
```

How can loop through the **nested** objects get the values and load it into the expendable listview?

Can someone help me and explain it a bit, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: chargingPointID is an object, not an int - you can't use it in a for loop like that.  If every object has a single ChargingPointID sub-object, why do you need a for loop?

Comment: @Jason Yes, I know charchingPointID is an object. But want to put the items in charchinPointID in the childview of the expendablelistview. So I thought I also need to loop through it to get the values. Or do I have a totally wrong idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

It was pretty easy. (Don't know why I didn't came up with this solution earlier).

Just added an extra list to store the items of the object charchingPointID. 
And then juist loop over that extra list, and voila! :)

```
void CreateExpendableListData ()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count; i++) {
            var lstChild = new List<string> ();

            var test = new List<string> ();
            test.Add ("Address: " + sorted [i].chargingPointID.address);
            test.Add ("Type: " + sorted [i].chargingPointID.type);
            test.Add ("Price: €" + sorted [i].chargingPointID.price.ToString ());

            for (int j = 0; j < test.Count; j++) {
                lstChild.Add (test [j]);
                Console.WriteLine (test [j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("TEST LOOP: ", sorted [i].chargingPointID.address);
            dictGroup.Add (string.Format (Convert.ToDateTime (sorted [i].startTime).ToShortDateString ()), lstChild);
        }

        lstKeys = new List<string> (dictGroup.Keys);
    }
```